# Is it possible to automatically generate constructors based on sub-interfaces? (with or without Lombok)

Tags: java, constructor, interface, annotations, lombok

Use the following code as an example.

Would it be possible to automatically generate `MySuperInterfaceImpl(MyInterface myInterface, double myDouble)`?

I prefer to avoid `lombok.Builder` because it can introduces problems with NullPointerException.

Another mention is that using `@lombok.experimental.Delegate` and `@lombok.AllArgsConstructor` would swap constructors, so in this case I'd ask how to generate the constructor of `MySuperInterfaceImpl(String myString, int myInt, long myLong, double myDouble)`. Honestly I prefer this implementation.

```java
interface MyInterface {
    String getMyString();
    int getMyInt();
    long getMyLong();
}

@lombok.Value
class MyInterfaceImpl implements MyInterface {
    String myString;
    int myInt;
    long myLong;
}

interface MySuperInterface extends MyInterface {
    double getMyDouble();
}

@lombok.Value
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
class MySuperInterfaceImpl implements MySuperInterface {
    String myString;
    int myInt;
    long myLong;
    double myDouble;

    /**
    * It would be great if I could hide/automatically generate this constructor with an annotation
    */
    MySuperInterfaceImpl(MyInterface myInterface, double myDouble) {
        this(myInterface.getMyString(), myInterface.getMyInt(), myInterface.getMyLong(), myDouble);
    }
}

@lombok.Value
@lombok.AllArgsConstructor
class MySuperInterfaceImpl2 implements MySuperInterface {
    @Delegate MyInterface myInterface;
    double myDouble;

    /**
    * It would be great if I could hide/automatically generate this constructor with an annotation
    */
    MySuperInterfaceImpl(String myString, int myInt, long myLong, double myDouble)
        this(new MyInterface() {
            String myString() { return myString; }
            int myInt() { return myInt; }
            long myLong() { return myLong; }
        }, myDouble);
    }
}
```

Comment: How is it meant to know which instance of MyInterface you want to use as the delegate?

Comment: @MrR the exactly `MyInterface`, not any other specific implementation as it is exemplified in the second `MySuperInterfaceImpl` constructor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there is no clean way to do this without using `@SuperBuilder`
See issue [2646](https://github.com/rzwitserloot/lombok/issues/2646)

For what it is worth the cleanest `@SuperBuilder` example that doesn't require explicit constructor definitions is below.

Note that I am also setting the following in my `lombok.config`:

```
lombok.equalsAndHashCode.callSuper = CALL
lombok.toString.callSuper = CALL
```

```java
import lombok.Value;
import lombok.experimental.NonFinal;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

public class So66862187 {

    
    /**
     * The Interface MyInterface.
     */
    interface MyInterface {

        /**
         * Gets the my string.
         *
         * @return the my string
         */
        String getMyString();

        /**
         * Gets the my int.
         *
         * @return the my int
         */
        int getMyInt();

        /**
         * Gets the my long.
         *
         * @return the my long
         */
        long getMyLong();
    }

    /**
     * Since we want our implementations to be final we need a common abstract super class
     */
    @Value
    @NonFinal
    @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
    public static abstract class AbstractMyInterface implements MyInterface {
        
        /** The my string. */
        String myString;

        /** The my int. */
        int myInt;

        /** The my long. */
        long myLong;
    }

    /**
     * The Class MyInterfaceImpl.
     */
    @Value
    @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
    public static class MyInterfaceImpl extends AbstractMyInterface {}


    /**
     * The Interface MySuperInterface.
     */
    interface MySuperInterface extends MyInterface {

        /**
         * Gets the my double.
         *
         * @return the my double
         */
        double getMyDouble();
    }

    /**
     * <p>This class is optional. If there is only going to be on implementation of {@link MySuperInterface} you don't need it.
     */
    @Value
    @NonFinal
    @SuperBuilder(toBuilder = true)
    public static abstract class AbstractMySuperInterface extends AbstractMyInterface implements MySuperInterface {

        /** The my double. */
        double myDouble;

    }

    /**
     * The Class MySuperInterfaceImpl.
     */
    @Value
    @SuperBuilder
    public static class MySuperInterfaceImpl extends AbstractMySuperInterface {}

}
```

Comment: It seems pretty much what I was looking for, thank you ♥

Comment: @Leobastiani Great!  Would you mind accepting the the answer?